# How to Change the schema of SDE dataset in Connected environment

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, schema-architecture, replication

We continuously use to receive changes in Schema ( field +/-, domain changes etc )  for our Utility dataset..

Since we have swicthed to a multiuser Geodatabase ( ArcSDE on Oracle ) , we would like to make apply this schema changes without affecting our current workflow.

How can we change\update the new schema on our existing SDE dataset , with minimal stoppage of the workflow ? One easy way would be to remove the existing dataset and configuring the new dataset ( which has new schema ) but wouldnt that make the existing completed jobs incompatible with the new schema ?

A quick response from experts highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get geodatabase x-ray from ArcGIS gallery. This tool will let you compare schemas, reorder fields, update schema, etc. I've used it with fgdb and MS SQL gdb. Both cases work well. Should be OK with Oracle too.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e1e911d7d7374285b1ef03d06b3ee642